# How to use a function multiple times to dump text to the console.log

Tags: javascript

I have literally just started started looking at JS in the past couple of days. I have been reading up on variables and functions and the problem I am trying to solve is creating a very simple getWeather app.

The goal of the app is the following:

> Create a function called getWeather that will have 2 parameters. One >called country and one called weatherType. Call the getWeather >function with 2 arguments. The first should be “Scotland”, the second >should be “sunny”. Your function should return the String “The weather >in Scotland is sunny”. Wrap the call to getWeather in a console.log() >to print out the String. Call the getWeather function two more times >with countries and weatherTypes of your choice.

This is the code that I have come up with so far:

```
// Function to store both parameteres.
const getWeather = (country, weatherType);

var country = 'Scotland';
var weatherType = 'sunny';

// Dumps the weather results to the console.
{console.log(`The weather in ${country} is ${weatherType}.`)};
```

So far I have it dumping "The weather in Scotland is sunny."

But I need to be able to dump multiple statements to the console, for example:

The weather in Scotland is sunny.
The weather in England is raining.
The weather in Wales is overcast.
The weather in Ireland is thunder.

I have tried using code like:

```
let getWeather = ('Scotland, sunny')
let getWeather = ('England, raining')
```

But this throws an error, can anyone point in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mis-defined the function:

```
const getWeather = (country, weatherType);
```

should be

```
const getWeather = (country, weatherType) => `The weather in ${country} is ${weatherType}.`;
```

Although I prefer

```
function getWeather(country, weatherType) {
    return `The weather in ${country} is ${weatherType}.`;
}
```

*There are a number of variations as to how to declare functions. see [Function Declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) and [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) if you want to start digging*

---

Calling

```
let getWeather = ('Scotland, sunny')
let getWeather = ('England, raining')
```

Attempts to override the function itself. Not good.

(EDIT: It also tries to redefine a variable of the same name. Bad. [good catch by @EsliS]);

Also, you've forgotten the "inner" quote marks, so you're passing single params : `('Scotland, sunny')` should be `('Scotland', 'sunny')`

---

Repeating is referred to iteration. look at [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).
But it might be too soon for that. In your case, you could just call the getWeather function multiple times:

```
console.log(getWeather(('Scotland', 'sunny')));
console.log(getWeather(('England', 'rainy')));
```

Comment: Also you're not allowed to redefine a `let`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I understand all of it apart from what the => is doing, could you explain?

Comment: It's an alternative syntax to declare a function called "arrow function". I've edited in an explanation link. But don't rush to know everything at once.

Answer (score 3):

You want to create a function with two parameters, then console.log those parameters in the function's body.

```js
    function getWeather(country, weatherType) {
        console.log(`The weather in ${country} is ${weatherType}.`);
    }
    
    getWeather("Wales", "Sunny");
    getWeather("Netherlands", "Dank");
```

Or you could return the sentence and then console.log the result, which is slightly better practice since you normally don't want to echo from a function.

```js
    function getWeather(country, weatherType) {
        return `The weather in ${country} is ${weatherType}.`;
    }
    
    console.log(getWeather("Wales", "Sunny"));
    console.log(getWeather("Netherlands", "Dank"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the task suggest that I use const rather than function though I do see the benefit of both solutions.

Comment: Yeah sorry @DezUk didn't know that. Didn't specify that in the question so I used a function since I prefer functions for readability and hoisting.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below

```js
const getWeather = (country, weatherType) => {
    return `The weather in ${country} is ${weatherType}.`;
  };
  
console.log(getWeather('Australia','Hot'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I like the use of return but again I see the arrow function. Why is this needed?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I have ended up using

```
// Variable to store both parameteres and return their values.
const getWeather = (country, weatherType) => {
    return `The weather in ${country} is ${weatherType}.`;
  };

// Dumps the weather results to the console.
console.log(getWeather('Scotland', 'miserable as usual'))
console.log(getWeather('United States', 'sunny and hot'))
console.log(getWeather('Russia', 'cold and snowing'))
```